# Magento 2 Service Contracts and WebApi

Tags: magento2, webapi, service-contract

I have implemented the Magento 2 Service Contracts, everything is working as expected, I can use my repository's `getById` and `getList` in Controller but as we know we can use Service Contracts for RestAPI so I have implemented API using webapi.xml but it is not working.

My RepositoryInterface `Vendor/Module/Api/TestRepositoryInterface.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

use \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;

interface TestRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @api
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface $Test
     * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface
     */
    public function save(TestInterface $Test);

    /**
     * @api
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface $Test
     * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface
     */
    public function delete(TestInterface $Test);

    /**
     * @api
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteById($id);

    /**
     * @api
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getById($id);

    /**
     * @api
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria
     * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function getList(SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria);
}
```

My Repository `Vendor/Module/Model/TestRepository.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface;
use \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test as ObjectResourceModel;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResultsInterfaceFactory;

class TestRepository implements \Vendor\Module\Api\TestRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $objectFactory;

    protected $objectResourceModel;

    protected $collectionFactory;

    protected $searchResultsFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory $objectFactory,
        ObjectResourceModel $objectResourceModel,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory
    ) {
        $this->objectFactory        = $objectFactory;
        $this->objectResourceModel  = $objectResourceModel;
        $this->collectionFactory    = $collectionFactory;
        $this->searchResultsFactory = $searchResultsFactory;
    }

    public function save(TestInterface $object)
    {
        try {
            $this->objectResourceModel->save($object);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        return $object;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getById($id)
    {
        $object = $this->objectFactory->create();
        $this->objectResourceModel->load($object, $id);
        if (!$object->getId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Object with id "%1" does not exist.', $id));
        }
        return $object;
    }

    public function delete(TestInterface $object)
    {
        try {
            $this->objectResourceModel->delete($object);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new CouldNotDeleteException(__($exception->getMessage()));
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function deleteById($id)
    {
        return $this->delete($this->getById($id));
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getList(SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria)
    {
        $searchResults = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
        $searchResults->setSearchCriteria($criteria);
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($criteria->getFilterGroups() as $filterGroup) {
            $fields = [];
            $conditions = [];
            foreach ($filterGroup->getFilters() as $filter) {
                $condition = $filter->getConditionType() ? $filter->getConditionType() : 'eq';
                $fields[] = $filter->getField();
                $conditions[] = [$condition => $filter->getValue()];
            }
            if ($fields) {
                $collection->addFieldToFilter($fields, $conditions);
            }
        }
        $searchResults->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
        $sortOrders = $criteria->getSortOrders();
        if ($sortOrders) {
            /** @var SortOrder $sortOrder */
            foreach ($sortOrders as $sortOrder) {
                $collection->addOrder(
                    $sortOrder->getField(),
                    ($sortOrder->getDirection() == SortOrder::SORT_ASC) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'
                );
            }
        }
        $collection->setCurPage($criteria->getCurrentPage());
        $collection->setPageSize($criteria->getPageSize());
        $objects = [];
        foreach ($collection as $objectModel) {
            $objects[] = $objectModel;
        }
        $searchResults->setItems($objects);
        return $searchResults;
    }

}
```

My DI `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\TestRepositoryInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\TestRepository" />
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Test" />
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\TestSearchResultInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\TestSearchResult" />
</config>
```

My WebAPI `Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="GET" url="/V1/testing/:id">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\TestRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route method="GET" url="/V1/testing">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\TestRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

If I access **test.local/rest/V1/testing/1** I end up with the following result (nothing),

[image]

If I pass non-existent id it throws an exception or if I use `die()` in the `getById` method it works but somehow not returning actual data.

Whereas if I access **test.local/rest/V1/testing** it gives me the following result, even though I am using `<resource ref="anonymouns"/>`

[image]

When I created an integration (although it shouldn't be required) to access **test.local/rest/V1/testing** I encountered the following error.

[image]

Above error is obvious because the `getList` has mandatory parameter `$criteria` but I don't know how to pass because `$criteria` param has `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface` type.

Remember integration is not working with **test.local/rest/V1/testing/1** either, it gives me nothing as above relevant screenshot.

What I am missing? Definitely, I am doing something wrong/silly but what it is? I would like to make it work.

**test.local/rest/V1/testing/1** for single record from the database table
**test.local/rest/V1/testing** for all records of the table

I didn't implement other `method` under `webapi.xml` because I have stuck at the start of the API journey :)

Please HELP (help-flag)

### Update

---

Thanks @raumatbel for the correction, there was a typo in webapi.xml it was **anonymouns** instead of anonymous, silly isn't it? :)

I am searching using REST endpoints with the following URL

```
test.local/rest/V1/testing?criteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_name&criteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%na%&criteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

[image]

`total_count` is 1 but `items` node is empty.

No results in either URL
**test.local/rest/V1/testing/1** or **test.local/rest/V1/testing** both are empty with no errors.

Comment: If you use the method *getById()* in your code of Magento, does it work? can you review your model and resource model?

Comment: Yes it is working

Comment: Can you share the code of your custom module in a .zip or .tar? If I download and install it, i can debug and find a solution fastly.

Comment: here you go https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z5l4auRwgKE4I5j548SJOVsSaHZrGEgD

Comment: @raumatbel Hi, did you get a chance to check the code?

Comment: Sorry, I have not checked yet, but tomorrow I think that I will can check it. Sorry

Comment: I know what is the problem. I update the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem is the name of resource in your **webapi.xml** for the method **getList()**

You have written **anonymouns** instead of **anonymous**

If you want use this api, you must do it as indicated by Magento in your doc. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/performing-searches.html

The problem is in your custom model and interface. The webapi retrieve the information if you have defined it in your custom model.

> Ad/Shipping/Api/Data/QuoteInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Ad\Shipping\Api\Data;

interface QuoteInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve the id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId();

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setId($id);

    /**
     * Retrieve the product id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductId();

    /**
     * Set product id
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProductId($productId);

    /**
     * Retrieve the customerName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerName();

    /**
     * Set customer name
     *
     * @param string $customerName
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCustomerName($customerName);

    ...
}
```

> Ad/Shipping/Model/Quote.php

```
<?php

namespace Ad\Shipping\Model;

class Quote extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements
    \Ad\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Ad\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote');
    }

    public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->_getData('product_id');
    }

    public function setProductId($productId)
    {
        $this->setData('product_id', $productId);
    }

    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->_getData('customer_name');
    }

    public function setCustomerName($customerName)
    {
        $this->setData('customer_name', $customerName);
    }

    ...
}
```

You need add the remaining data (**customer_email, customer_comments, date_added, date_updated**)

You can read my post blog about this.
https://www.interactiv4.com/blog-es/nueva-entidad-en-magento-2/

The post is in Spanish, I had a English version, but it is not updated and published, I have pending to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, as I said, must be some silly mistake +1, I have updated my question after correction and implementation of search criteria (please see my question). Also, I am wondering why test.local/rest/V1/testing/1 is not returning any result.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes it worked, but I am confused, isn't the get and set is part of AbstractModel?

Comment: Abstract model have the methods getData() and setData(), but if you don't specify the methods in your interface and in your implementation, your api doesn't know what fields must return. https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access/ you can read this paragraph. "While not strictly necessary, the model specific TodoItemInterface interface plays an important role when it comes time to exporting CRUD models to Magento’s new service contracts based API. The model specific interfaces for Magento CRUD models will determine which class methods are available via the Magento API."

Comment: Ahan, "The model specific interfaces for Magento CRUD models will determine which class methods are available via the Magento API." ... right ... Thank you very much @raumatbel :)